# How to remove repeated headers in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have got a table in ssrs 2008 like that:

```
Replacement
Location       Date          
           Total  Missing
X          100    20
Location       Date          
           Total  Missing
Y          200    50
Location       Date          
           Total  Missing
Z          300    80
```

I want to get rid of the repeats of titles but I could not manage it. I check Tablix properties and see "Repeat header..." and "Keep header..." options are all unchecked. Note that the table is grouped by Row:Location and Column:Date.

How can I remove repeated headers?

I want something like:

```
Replacement
Location        Date
           Total   Missing
X          100     20
Y          200     50
Z          300     80
```

I appreciate for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group by Location appears to be on two rows of data, first row contains the title "Location" and the second row contains the expression =Location.

The group by Location needs to be on one row without the title in the grouping as denoted by the grouping handle.

[image]